# Loop and search in richtexbox for text

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I am trying to create a find and replace like in ms word. I have created a new `form` and added the `textbox` and findnext `button`.

The problem now i how to loop through the textbox and find the text one by one and highlight them.

I have tried

```
    private void btnFindNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmTextpad text = (frmTextpad)Application.OpenForms["frmTextpad"];
        int length = txtFind1.Text.Length;
        for (int a = 0; a >= 0; a++)
        {
            int location = text.Current.Find(text.Current.Text, a, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
            text.Current.Select(location, txtFind1.Text.Length);
            text.Current.SelectionBackColor = Color.Blue;
        }
    }
```

I get an `ArgumentOutofRangeException`.

Pls what am i doing wrong and how can i achieve what i want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for loop is never terminating and is running up through the end of the text block and outside the bounds of the string you're searching.

```
for (int a = 0; a >= 0; a++)
```

Will keep running as long as `int a` is greater than 0, which is forever since you never reduce it.  You will want to terminate the loop when it reaches a certain point (the length of the string you're searching).  Probably more like this:

```
for (int a = 0; a < text.Current.Text.Length; a++)
```

It also looks like you are searching your text box for its own text right here:

```
int location = text.Current.Find(text.Current.Text, a, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
```

I'm not familiar with the structure of your form but it looks like you want to search for the value of the `txtFind` control.  So what you want is more like this:

```
int location = text.Current.Find(txtFind1.Text, a, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at

```
  for (int a = 0; a >= 0; a++)
```

as of right now that for loop will never stop

so that should not be `a >= 0` it should be `a <= length`